# Generating random colored boxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like the title says I have been trying to make it so by typing in a number into the given form and pressing go it will generate that number of boxes with random colored backgrounds.

Here is the JS so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var number = 3;
function numBoxes(){

    var form = document.getElementById("form1");

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.children.length > 0) {
        container.removeChild(container.firstElementChild);
    }

    number = form.elements["number"].value;

    setup();
}

function setup(){

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var box = document.createElement("div");
        box.id = "newdiv"

        container.appendChild(box);
        var d = document.getElementById("newdiv");
        var colors = random_bg_color();
        d.style.backgroundColor = colors;

    }
}

function random_bg_color(){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
    return bgColor;
}

</script>
```

The only thing I have not been able to get to work is assigning a random rgb color to each newly created division or box.

Note: this is meant to be done without jQuery

Comment: the color css property is for text. you want `backgroundColor`

Comment: Sorry about that I already changed that to backgroundColor but the problem is still that only the first box has a random color all the other ones created have the default color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning same id to div every time. You just don't need to assign ID to created div at all, or generate a unique id every time. Here is a working example for 10 boxes. And color property is for text color. Use `backgroundColor` property to set styles.

```
function setup(){

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var box = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(box);
        var colors = random_bg_color();
        box.style.backgroundColor = colors;

    }
}

function random_bg_color(){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
    return bgColor;
}

setup()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9h26e8np/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");


function getRandomColor() {
  const max = 255;
  const min = 0;

  const val1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  const val2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  const val3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  return `rgb(${val1}, ${val2}, ${val3})`;
}
Array.from(boxes).forEach((e) => {
  e.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  e.style.color = getRandomColor();
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).